# Using wmctrl with zenity prompt causes budgie-wm segmentation fault

Tags: bash, workspaces, segmentation-fault, zenity, budgie

I'm attempting to write a bash script that switches between workspaces with some dialog prompts along the way. I'm running Ubuntu 17.04 with Budgie remix.

When using `wmctrl` or `zenity` separately, they both work fine. Put them together however and budgie window manager crashes with a segmentation fault.

This happens using both `wmctrl -s 0` and `xdotool set_desktop 0`. They work fine on their own but not in combination with `zenity`.

#### Here's my code (induces segmentation fault)

```
#!/bin/bash

desktop=$(xdotool get_desktop) #Get current workspace id

if [ "${desktop}" -eq 0 ] #If workspace == 0
then
  wmctrl -s 3 #Switch to workspace 3
  firefox --new-window "http://www.reddit.com"
else
    zenity --question --title "Switch Workspace?" --text "Are you sure you wish to return to previous workspace?"
    if ! $? #If response Yes
    then
      wmctrl -s 0 #Switch back
    else
      notify-send "Operation Aborted" "User canceled workspace return."
    fi
fi
```

#### Example of working code when `wmctrl` command is used alone

```
#!/bin/bash

desktop=$(xdotool get_desktop) #Get current workspace id

if [ "${desktop}" -eq 0 ] #If workspace == 0
then
  wmctrl -s 3 #Switch to workspace 3
  firefox --new-window "http://www.reddit.com"
else
  wmctrl -s 0 #Switch back
fi
```

#### Example of working code when `zenity` command is used alone

```
#!/bin/bash

desktop=$(xdotool get_desktop) #Get current workspace id

if [ "${desktop}" -eq 0 ] #If workspace == 0
then
  wmctrl -s 3 #Switch to workspace 3
  firefox --new-window "http://www.reddit.com"
else
    zenity --question --title "Switch Workspace?" --text "Are you sure you wish to return to previous workspace?"
    if ! $? #If response Yes
    then
      notify-send "Switch Workspace" "Operation placeholder."
    else
      notify-send "Operation Aborted" "User canceled workspace return."
    fi
fi
```

#### Here's what I've found within `journalctl`

```
Dec 02 11:17:54 main budgie-wm.desktop[20079]: Window manager warning: Received a NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP message from a broken (outdated) client who sent a 0 timestamp
Dec 02 11:17:54 main kernel: budgie-wm[20079]: segfault at 18 ip 00007fa255e8dfc1 sp 00007fff13189710 error 4 in libmutter-0.so.0.0.0[7fa255df0000+131000]
Dec 02 11:17:55 main gnome-session-binary[19810]: WARNING: Application 'budgie-wm.desktop' killed by signal 11
Dec 02 11:17:55 main gnome-session[19810]: gnome-session-binary[19810]: WARNING: Application 'budgie-wm.desktop' killed by signal 11
Dec 02 11:17:55 main ckb.desktop[20137]: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 148 (Unknown), sequence: 423, resource id: 0, major code: 140 (Unknown), minor code: 20
Dec 02 11:17:56 main budgie-wm[21537]: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
Dec 02 11:17:56 main budgie-wm[21537]: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

What is causing the segmentation fault when `zenity` is used to trigger the workspace switch yet both components work fine separately?

Comment: Please do not repost your question but rather [edit] it!

Comment: Please try `xdotool set_desktop 3` (or rather `0`).

Comment: @dessert,  this happens using both wmctrl -s 0 and xdotool set_desktop 0.

Comment: I vote to close this question because I think it's a bug in `zenity`. I suggest to search for it on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zenity and file a new bug if it's not already there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filed as bug within Zenity, see: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zenity/+bug/1735917